# C# class problem - object not being recognized

Tags: c#, streamreader

I have run into a problem in this program, where I cant get my Calcpay method to output in the right spot, its outputting wrong. I want it to output when the `computepay` button is clicked, but its not recognizing the object there, when I put `textbox7` under `openToolStripMenuItem1_Click` to test it, it came out as 0 anyways.
Thanks in advance for any help

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        //opens about page
        private void aboutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
        }
        //closes program
        private void exitToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
        //reads in data from text file, assigns to textboxes.
        private void openToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double emphours;
            double hourpay;
            Stream myStream = null;
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "text files (*.txt)|*txt";
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    StreamReader data = new StreamReader(myStream);
                    textBox1.Text = data.ReadLine();
                    textBox4.Text = data.ReadLine();
                    textBox2.Text = data.ReadLine();
                    textBox3.Text = data.ReadLine();
                    emphours = double.Parse(data.ReadLine());
                    hourpay = double.Parse(data.ReadLine());
                    Employee employ = new Employee(emphours, hourpay);
                    textBox5.Text = Convert.ToString(employ.EmpHours);
                    textBox6.Text = Convert.ToString(employ.EmpHourPay);
                }
            }
        }
        // The CalcPay_Clickmethod
        //  display employee net pay
                            private void computepay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                     // need to get calcpay method to output here
                                //textbox7.Text = xx  
        }
                }
            }

        public class Employee
    {

        const int TimeAndAHalfMarker = 40;
        const double Federaltax = .20;
        const double Statetax = .075;
        const double TimeAndAHalf = 0.5;
        private double netpay, grossPay, stateTax, federalTax;
        public double EmpHours { get; private set; }

        public double EmpHourPay { get; private set; }

        public Employee(double emphours, double emphourpay)
        {
            EmpHours = emphours;
            EmpHourPay = emphourpay;
        }

        public double Calcpay(double emphours, double emphourpay)
        {

            EmpHours = emphours;
            EmpHourPay = emphourpay;
            if (EmpHours > TimeAndAHalfMarker)
                grossPay += (((EmpHours - TimeAndAHalfMarker) * EmpHourPay) * TimeAndAHalf);
            federalTax = grossPay * Federaltax;
            stateTax = grossPay * Statetax;
            netpay = grossPay - stateTax - federalTax;

            return netpay;
        }
    }


}
```

a sample text file is:

> Mary R. Programmer
>
> 1237
>
> 17 North Elm Avenue
>
> 789-1000
>
> 40.0
>
> 15.00

Comment: This is the best title for a question ever... you get a lot of views.

Answer (score 2):

One problem is the following line of code, inside the `openToolStripMenuItem1_Click` event:

```
Employee employ = new Employee(emphours, hourpay);
```

**The instance `employ` needs to have a scope wide enough for other events on the form to access it.**

Thus I suggest putting `Employee employ;` on the form level and change the `openToolStripMenuItem1_Click` event to say:

```
employ = new Employee(emphours, hourpay);
```

Then you can reference employ in the button click event as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Your Employee class is not static and has to be instantiated. You've done this:

```
Employee employ = new Employee(emphours, hourpay);
```

However, you've declared `employ` only within the scope of that codeblock. Instead, declare it at class level. For example:

```
Employee employ
public Form1()
{
     InitializeComponent();
}
```

This `Employee` object will now be available anywhere in that class.

Within your click handler:

```
private void computepay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

       textbox7.Text = employ.CalcPay(employ.EmpHours, employ.EmpHoursPay).ToString();
}
```

Because `employ` is now available throughout the class, that object can call the `CalcPay` method and get the value. As a suggestion, now that you can see how an object works, you know that you don't need to explicitly add the `EmpHours` and `EmpHoursPay` to the `CalcPay` method. You would only need to do this if the object was static.

Answer (score 0):

CalcPay is a method of your Employee class, in order to call that method you need to be able to reference an instance of the class. You create an instance of that class in the stripmenu item event handler but you don't store it anywhere for later use.

So you need to either create a global or form level variable to store the instance (that you create in the strip menu handler), but you also need to be careful, creating the instance and using it from different event handlers means that your user will have to make sure that things are done in the right order...or that you do things like 1./ test that the instance is not null before calling it (you should do this anyway) and 2./ perhaps only enable the calc button after the Employee var is created.

One more point...name your UI elements!